# iPad Pro gaze detection to prevent display sleep

Tags: ipad, display, ios

Can/do the newly announced iPad Pros use the FaceID apparatus for gaze detection to prevent display sleep? This would be great to set the display sleep time to be after a certain period of non attention. Sometimes when I’m reading something I take my attention off the screen, then carry on reading, then suffer a spurt of non-attention, then the display turns off before I realise.

I’m wondering if FaceID is used to detect attention and prevent display sleep (and a cool bonus would be auto-dimming the screen when attention is not on the screen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Apple hasn't added this feature yet. They [patented this](https://appleinsider.com/articles/15/01/20/apple-patents-eye-tracking-gaze-controls-for-ios-mac-devices) in 2015, but for some reason haven't done any more. There is a chance if enough people request the feature(you can do so [here](https://www.apple.com/feedback/)), Apple might decide to include this feature.